# Trying to extend a class in java and running into problems

Tags: constructor

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem I am encountering when trying to extend a class.  I want to be able to add a first name and a last name which is part of my base class to an extended class.

Here is a snippet from my base class Person.java

```
public class Person
{
    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";
    private String id = "";


    public Person()
    {

    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String id)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.id = id;
    }
```

And here is the class where I am trying to extend the base class:

```
 public TeamMember(String firstName, String lastName, String team, String id, String role)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.team = team;
        this.id = id;
        this.role = role;
    }
```

The error I receive is:

Error:(25, 9) java: constructor Person in class xxx.xxxx.xxx.xx
cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a constructor that matched what was in the super() in the extended class in the base class.

This is what I added to the base class to make it work.

```
 public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public TeamMember(String firstName, String lastName, String team, String id, String role)
{
    super(firstName, lastName, id);
    this.team = team;
    this.role = role;
}
```

Id is a private property of base class, so cannot be accessed in derived class.

```
private String id = "";
```